# Can we write the differentiability of a function in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by using any basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, metric-spaces, change-of-basis

Whenever we deal with functions such as $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, when we defined the notion of differentiability or the directional derivative, we use the coordinates $(1,0,...,0), (0,...,1,...,0)$ etc.. However, is it possible to use the same rules and definitions to show the differentiability of a function or find its directional derivate using **any** basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (maybe particularly only using any orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$).

So for example, if $u, v$ is any 2 linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and $x_1, x_2$ is the standart basis of $\mathbb{R}$, does the following equality 
$$D_{x_1} f * dx_1 + D_{x_2} f * dx_2 = D_u f * du + D_v f * d_v$$
hold ? If so, how can we prove it ?

Comment: You can define total differentiability without using coordinates by linear approximations, see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative#The_total_derivative_as_a_linear_map. If you want to change the coordinates the chain-rule should come in handy, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule#Higher_dimensions

Comment: It is usually covered in vector calculus/real analysis textbooks.